# Can I get access to the series legend text from the tooltip expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When setting a tooltip expression for the chart series, is it possible to access the same series' `legend text`? What would be the syntax? I just want to aviod having to type the same literal in two places. I.e. instead of

```
=Fields!Metric.Value +  ", Literal : " + FormatNumber(Fields!Data.Value, 2)
```

I would like to use whatever syntax for the Series/Legend Text:

```
=Fields!Metric.Value + Series.LegendText + FormatNumber(Fields!Data.Value, 2)
```